# SQL Server 2012 : DATEDIFF function in terms of years, days and months

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, date-difference

I am using the `DATEDIFF` function in SQL Server 2012. I have two dates, `2015-01-01` and `current_date`. I need `DATEDIFF` in terms of *Years , Months & Days* between these two dates. below are my statements :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YY, '2015-01-01', GETDATE()) AS 'Years'
SELECT DATEDIFF(MM, '2015-01-01', GETDATE()) AS 'Months'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DD, '2015-01-01', GETDATE()) AS 'Days'
```

The result I am getting is: Years = 3, Months = 46, Days = 1416

Why in months & days it is adding an extra year?

Comment: SELECT `DATEDIFF(YY, '2015-12-31', '2016-01-01')` is one year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATEDIFF()` measures the number of time boundaries between two date/time values.

So, with `year`, it measures the number of times that the year flips (i.e. that new years start).

With `month`, it measures the number of times that the month flips (i.e. that new months start).

With `day`, it measures the number of times that the day flips (i.e. that new days start).

These are all independent of each other.

I would recommend that you *not* try to get the value in years/months/days.  This is a hard problem.  What is the number of months/days between Feb 28 and Mar 31?  Between Jan 31 and Feb 28?  Between Jan 31 and Mar 31?  They don't add up, making this a hard problem.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a little overkill, but if you are open to a TVF

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeDate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('2015-01-01')

Select A.SomeDate
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed](SomeDate,GetDate()) B
```

**Returns**

```
SomeDate    Years   Months  Days    Hours   Minutes Seconds
2015-01-01  3       10      16      8       22      40
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          --,[Elapsed] = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')
```

Comment: This works pretty well. One result this returns that I would disagree with would be between `20160229` and `20170328`; the return value is 1 year 1 month. Personally I would suggest that it's 1 year 28 days (as the value of days is lower than the start), however, leap years are always "fun" trouble makers. :)

Comment: @Larnu In your scenario, you're spanning a leap year, so it is 1 month.  If you were to  try 20160229 - 20160328 you would get 28 days.   At least this is how I count.   That said, I appreciate the challenge  :)

Comment: I agree, `20160229`-`20160328` is 28 days, but that's why I also feel that `20160229` -`20170328` is 1 year 28 days (not 1 year 1 month).  Like wise, I wouldn't say that `20160229`-`20170329` is 1 year 1 day, but 1 year 1 month. But, like I said, leap years are always "trouble makers".

Comment: @larnu I think the only sensible criteria is that the results should be usable in `DATEADD()` to go from `@D1` to `@D2`.  But, then, the order you add the intervals matters; `DATEADD(DAY, 29, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, '2015-01-31'))  !=  DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 29, '2015-01-31'))` *(Adding the largest interval first makes sense to me)*.  Equally, however, multiple legitimate answers are possible; `DATEADD(DAY, 28, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, '2016-02-29')) == DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, '2016-02-29'))`

Comment: @larnu (and John) : comments on this attempt?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=56649374de812a6e01ec736f73f5ec40

Comment: @MatBailie Impressive, but when I test 2016-02-29 - 2017-03-28 I get 11 Months and 58 days.  Other than that my TVF matches your results (sans the milliseconds)   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c2f9b7a90ebc79c66ad0d367bbcb4d41

Comment: @JohnCappelletti The difference is that in some cases the TVF here gives the same interval between two dates even when adding 1 more day to the "start date" *(because adding a month to `2018-01-28` gives the same result as adding a month to `2018-01-31`)*, but the linked method doesn't *(See rows 3, 4, 5 of the link in this comment)*.  As for the mistake, I've corrected that to make one adjustment or the other, but not both, thanks :) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6c4a647b91f031692a3b348cca1c397f

Comment: @MatBailie Here is a better illustration.  You will see how each bucket decreases.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f88afb37edffd3dc5ceda06b43fc9e55

Comment: This one shows a few more cases where neighbouring input rows give the same result as each other. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2680edd3eb2b805b1ab0864a905d18ca

Comment: @MatBailie I see what you are saying now.  Going revisit the logic.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My take on @JohnCappelletti's inspired answer

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_interval_parts] (@start DateTime, @cease DateTime)
Returns Table
RETURN
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      months / 12   AS years,
      months % 12   AS months
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH, months, @start) > @cease                           THEN months - 1
             WHEN DATEADD(MONTH, months, @start) = DATEADD(MONTH, months, @start-1) THEN months - 1
                                                                                    ELSE months     END   AS months
      FROM
      (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @start, @cease) AS months
      )
        provisional
    )
      adjusted
  )
    interim
  CROSS APPLY
  (
      SELECT
        milliseconds                         / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  AS days,
        milliseconds % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / (     60 * 60 * 1000)  AS hours,
        milliseconds % (     60 * 60 * 1000) / (          60 * 1000)  AS minutes,
        milliseconds % (          60 * 1000) / (               1000)  AS seconds,
        milliseconds % (               1000)                          AS milliseconds
      FROM
      (
        SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(millisecond, DATEADD(MONTH, 12 * years + months, @start), @cease) AS milliseconds
      )
        provisional
  )
    remainder
```

Example usage here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=47b2d437c4cea78d182ce0f63772ef38

Comment: Only the truly obsessed down to the millisecond  :)   +1